# I am unable to get environment names from an array

Tags: javascript, java, spring, jsp

I have an array in which the environment list is stored and from this list, I have to get all the environment names which I am unable to get right now. See below what I have tried and please help me out of this.

```
<script> 
//${environmentList} is getting from backend i.e from modal class in which toString() method has stored with all its contents.
  var envLength = `${environmentList}`.length;
  var allEnv = `${environmentList}`;
  console.log("All Environments : " + allEnv);
  console.log("Length of environments : " + envLength);

  for(let i = 0 ; i < envLength ; i++){ 
    let all = `${allEnv[i].environmentName}`;    
    console.log("Environment Name : " + all[i]);  
} 
 </script>
```

> toString() method :

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "EnvironmentModel [environmentId=" + environmentId + ", environmentName=" + environmentName
            + ", environmentDesc=" + environmentDesc + ", hostAddress=" + hostAddress + ", environmentURL="
            + environmentURL + ", configFileName=" + configFileName + ", configFilePath=" + configFilePath
            + ", companyId=" + companyId + ", createdBy=" + createdBy + ", createdAt=" + createdAt
            + ", lastUpdatedBy=" + lastUpdatedBy + ", lastUpdatedAt=" + lastUpdatedAt + ", elementFileName="
            + elementFileName + ", elementFilePath=" + elementFilePath + ", envStatus=" + envStatus + ", projectId="
            + projectId + ", project=" + project + "]";
}
```

> OUTPUT:

**All Environments :**

> [EnvironmentModel [environmentId=345, environmentName=MM_Env_1, environmentDesc=Environment_1, hostAddress=null, environmentURL=null, configFileName=SystemFile.xml, configFilePath=/env_files/MM_Env_1, companyId=1, createdBy=2, createdAt=2019-12-18 16:39:38.595, lastUpdatedBy=2, lastUpdatedAt=2019-12-18 16:42:13.259, elementFileName=ElementFile.xml, elementFilePath=/env_files/MM_Env_1, envStatus=1, projectId=null, project=[Project [projectName=Magic Matrix, projectDescription=Magic Matrix is a significant and robust tool of the Solitera Software Company., projectId=23]]], EnvironmentModel [environmentId=346, environmentName=MM_Env_2, environmentDesc=Environment_2, hostAddress=null, environmentURL=null, configFileName=soapAPI_request_GetLyrics.xml, configFilePath=/env_files/MM_Env_2, companyId=1, createdBy=2, createdAt=2019-12-18 16:43:10.59, lastUpdatedBy=2, lastUpdatedAt=2019-12-18 16:43:58.522, elementFileName=Element.xml, elementFilePath=/env_files/MM_Env_2, envStatus=1, projectId=null, project=[Project [projectName=Magic Matrix, projectDescription=Magic Matrix is a significant and robust tool of the Solitera Software Company., projectId=23]]], EnvironmentModel [environmentId=347, environmentName=TM_Env_1, environmentDesc=TM_Env_1, hostAddress=null, environmentURL=null, configFileName=showcasetestData.xml, configFilePath=/env_files/TM_Env_1, companyId=1, createdBy=2, createdAt=2019-12-18 16:44:33.783, lastUpdatedBy=2, lastUpdatedAt=2019-12-18 16:44:47.09, elementFileName=soapAPI_request_TempConvert.xml, elementFilePath=/env_files/TM_Env_1, envStatus=1, projectId=null, project=[Project ...

**Length of environments :** `2235`

**Environment Name :** `undefined`

Comment: can you replace this in your for loop: `let all = `${allEnv[i]environmentName}`; `

Comment: Make your life easier, and use an established data exchange format, like JSON.

Comment: @Sandeep Kumar: I have also used 'var' in place of 'let' but it didn't work. I am getting the same output.

Comment: If you have controll over the backend, the I agree with @Teemu and suggest you'll use JSON.

Comment: I meant remove `.` after allEvn[i]`

Comment: @slt_rajan why not make a simple rest service and call that?

Comment: @DanielderGrosse:Yeah you both are right but the problem is this -> Previously, I have used Jackson JSON parser but somehow it throws catch exception and only gives me the null Values and for simple purpose, I have used the toString() method and with the help of this, I am able to get the environment list.

Comment: @SandeepKumar It didn't work sir. ```org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.el.ELException: Failed to parse the expression [${allEnv[i]environmentName}]```

Comment: This really should be fixed at the server-side. I'd suggest you to ask a new question of why the JSON conversion failed in your Java code, and fix the issue at its origin instead of creating a hack.

Comment: @Teemu Okay I'll try it in that way !! Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Use Jackson json parser in Java class and in javascript side use JSON.parse to change the string to JSON object.

Comment: Previously, I have used Jackson JSON parser but somehow it throws catch exception and only gives me the null Values and for simple purpose, I have used the toString() method and with the help of this, I am able to get the environment list.

Comment: @slt_rajan since you have the string in different pattern the logic may contain with regex and split functions. if you use JSON parse the logic will hold the less effort.

Answer (score 0):

On the javascript side you'll should understand that the variable environmentList is a string and the length of the string is 2235 chars. To access each property you'll have to parse the string and turn it into an object.

As you are not relying on JSON you need to use `String.split` or a regex matcher.

But the simpler solution would be to convert the Environment variables into a JSON format. As the type of the output from `System.getenv()` is a `Map<string, string>` you can try this solution to create a JSON structure: [Converting Map<String,String> into json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12817630/converting-mapstring-string-into-json#12819776)

After that you'll either write the json in a script tag in HTML so it get's parsed directly, or user JSON parse on the string of the above solution.